# What is the exact meaning of "I wouldn't have it any other way"?

Tags: meaning, expressions, social-media

What is the exact meaning of "I wouldn't have it any other way"?

I've seen this sentence used massively by people on social media posts. Hence I searched about this on Google but couldn't understand the exact meaning.

What I have found in my research is given below:

*I wouldn't want to change a thing* implies that I am happy with it. That is the way that I like it, and I would not allow that to be different, and that I wouldn't change anything, even if I could.

But people on social media use it like it means "There is no other way that I can have this".

Comment: Look at the phrase as saying "There is no other way that I *would want to* have this."

Comment: @YosefBaskin It often follows a description of some of the negative aspects of someone's life but is added to say that the disadvantages are worth it for the deep emotional or spiritual benefit that they gain. For example someone with a child with physical challenges and severe learning difficulties might describe the daily challenges of their life then say "But I wouldn't have it any other way" because of the deep satisfaction they have gained from their relationship.

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wouldn-t-have-it-any-other-way

Answer (score 0):

The results of your research are correct and its typical usage is as BoldBen  described.

When we say the line we emphasize the word "way".

*I wouldn't have it any other **way***.

If, instead, we were to emphasize the word "have"

*I wouldn't **have** it any other way*

it could be interpreted as "there is no other way that I can *have* this."

But if that is indeed what the people on social media are trying to say, there are better ways to say it! For example,

*It's the only way I can have this.*